# EB Deploy to multiple environments

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have the same codebase (one git repository) that I want to upload to multiple elastic beanstalk environments. Is there a way to do this, and if so how should I set up my repository in such a way that I can push to multiple environments?

The environments are different language versions of the site, that I want to run in different beanstalks. The language is set by the environment parameters.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To answer my own question. The AWS EB CLI 3+ has a nice interface to deploy to multiple environments. If you add another environment to your application you can simply deploy by using

```
eb deploy <environment-name>
```

Comment: is there a way to do this with the `config.yml` file?

Comment: can you execute only one command to deploy to multiple environments?
e.g. 

```eb deploy <environment-1> <environment-2>```

Comment: @HueyLy it seems at this time that's not possible. But you can do `eb deploy <env1> -v && eb deploy <env2> -v` and so on.. ;)

Comment: I have made a proposal to the EB team to allow for this: https://github.com/aws/elastic-beanstalk-roadmap/issues/165

Answer (score 16):

You can make the eb cli refer to different environments from different branches by adding config like the following to your `.elasticbeanstalk/config.yml` file:

```
branch-defaults:
  main:
    environment: staging
  production:
    environment: production
```

In this example When you run `eb deploy` from the "main" branch, it will deploy to your environment named "staging", whereas when you run it from the "production" branch, it will deploy to your environment named "production".

This approach requires each environment have a dedicated branch.  To push one branch to multiple environments, you can use [@adnan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30301576/2800876) and specify a branch when you use the `eb deploy` command:

```
eb deploy <environment_name>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you specify the version label you can use that version in the other `eb deploy` commands:

```sh
eb deploy my-first-env -l version-1 && eb deploy my-second-env --version version-1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using git and have a branch for each environment:

```
git checkout master
eb use <environment-name>

git checkout staging
eb use <environment-name>

git checkout worker
eb use <environment-name>
```

Then you can simply

`eb deploy`

Which will deploy to the defined environment for the current branch.

Under the hood this sets the association in `/.elasticbeanstalk/config.yml`

You can still `eb deploy <environment-name>` from any branch though.

Answer (score 0):

I did little workaround without having to upload same source code. First I deploy my "main" environment, then I check for its version and finally deploy this version to the second one. Also it can be modified to use different environment based on current git branch.

Example for 2 different environments (apps) using same source code:

My `config.yaml` file for "main" environment

```yaml
branch-defaults:
  main:
    environment: environ1-prod
  dev:
    environment: environ1-dev
...
```

```sh
# this deploys environ1 based on config.yaml
eb deploy 

BRANCH="$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)"
APP_VERSION="$(eb status | sed -n 's/.*Version: //p')"

if [ "$BRANCH" = "main" ]; then
  eb deploy environ2-prod --version $APP_VERSION
elif [ "$BRANCH" = "dev" ]; then
  eb deploy environ2-dev --version $APP_VERSION
fi
```